# Git: Auto commit contents of a windows folder

Tags: windows, git, version-control

We have a shared folder on our network. Is there a way to auto commit and push the changes of the folder (say every hour) to the remote Stash repository?
Thanks.

Comment: You could run a script that adds/commits/pushes the changes and then waits for an hour..?

Comment: Like using a Task Scheduler? Will it have to be like a C# executable? How will I run it when my laptop is turned off?

Comment: @poke +1 even if it is a bad practice for me because versionning is giving sens (with a good comment) to an atomic commit with human choosen changes...

Comment: You can use a task scheduler but you can also just use a program that just runs forever and sleeps for an hour between any execution. And no, it doesn’t have to be C#; you can do this in any programming language. And if your computer is turned off, of course it cannot push the changes on your laptop any longer…

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ah Apologies, I was referring to Atlassian Stash

Answer (score 3):

There's a bunch of opensource tools to do git autocommit. However, they solve a slightly different task: making a commit just after a change is detected.

https://github.com/mvgrimes/git-autocommit

https://github.com/riddochc/git-autocommit

Also, you can make a batch file and schedule it to run each hour:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd path/to/your/project
git add --all
timestamp() {
  date +"at %H:%M:%S on %d/%m/%Y"
}
git commit -am "Regular auto-commit $(timestamp)"
git push
```

<strike>If anyone knows how to insert a timestamp in batch file, you're welcome to edit this answer.</strike>

Comment: It may raise a conflict and will stop working form this point until someone will fix it.

Comment: Sure, this may (and probably will) happen. This is why I recommend to use an external tool and not self-made bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you convert the folder to a git project and then by adding hooks it can do what ever you want on every commit and or push that was made.

If its not a git repository you will need some other third party to handle it for you.